# Jquery directional transitions not working when put in container div

Tags: jquery, css

I have built a directional transition gallery and I went to put it on a site I'm building and
the directional transition completely fails. I have tried everything i can think of, but I can't get it working in a container.

[Js fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/unknown601/wL6rLsmq/13/)

```
    $(".gallery li").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function (e) {

      var w = $(this).width();
      var h = $(this).height();

      var x = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft - (w / 2)) * (w > h ? (h / w) : 1);
      var y = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop - (h / 2)) * (h > w ? (w / h) : 1);

      var direction = Math.round((((Math.atan2(y, x) * (180 / Math.PI)) + 180) / 90) + 3) % 4;

      /** check for direction **/
      switch (direction) {
          case 0:
              // direction top
              var slideFrom = {
                  "top": "-100%",
                      "right": "0"
              };
              var slideTo = {
                  "top": 0
              };
              var imgSlide = "0, 100";

              break;
          case 1:
              // direction right
              var slideFrom = {
                  "top": "0",
                      "right": "-100%"
              };
              var slideTo = {
                  "right": 0
              };
              var imgSlide = "-100, 0";

              break;
          case 2:
              // direction bottom
              var slideFrom = {
                  "top": "100%",
                      "right": "0"
              };
              var slideTo = {
                  "top": 0
              };
              var imgSlide = "0, -100";

              break;
          case 3:
              // direction left
              var slideFrom = {
                  "top": "0",
                      "right": "100%"
              };
              var slideTo = {
                  "right": 0
              };
              var imgSlide = "100, 0";

              break;
      }

      if (e.type === 'mouseenter') {
          var element = $(this);

          element.find(".info").removeClass("transform").css(slideFrom);
          element.find("img").addClass("transform-img").css("transform", "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1," + imgSlide + ")");

          setTimeout(function () {
              element.find(".info").addClass("transform").css(slideTo);
          }, 10);


      } else {
          var element = $(this);

          element.find(".info").addClass("transform").css(slideFrom);
          element.find("img").removeClass("transform-img").css("transform", "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1," + imgSlide + ")");

          setTimeout(function () {
              element.find("img").addClass("transform-img").css("transform", "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1,0,0)");
          }, 10);

      }
  });
```

Comment: A relative div won't work either, because its parent div is absolute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change how you calculate `x` and `y` into this:

```
var x = (e.pageX - $(this).offset().left - (w / 2)) * (w > h ? (h / w) : 1);
var y = (e.pageY - $(this).offset().top - (h / 2)) * (h > w ? (w / h) : 1);
```

Here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wL6rLsmq/14/)..